# Web api authorization by capturing client's service account name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

All, I am having an issue with implementing authorization on one of my web api controller action. This is a .net framework 4.6.1 app and an MVC 5 application makes calls into this web api.
We implement windows authentication both on the client(MVC5) and  web api. Both client and server use the same service account(The account name the app pool runs under) and these are on separate servers.

Users of the client app is authenticated using AD account before they get to the MVC app section that makes calls to the web api.

I added the [Authorize] attribute to the api controller action, but the request is returned with 401 unauthorized status.

So I added a custom authorization logic, that compares the incoming user name(service account) from the client app, against whats configured in the api's config file(in each environment) and accept/deny request.But the User (please see code below) on the line actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name is an empty string.

I tried enabling asp.net impersonation on the  MVC5 apps configuration on IIS, but still no luck

Has anyone done something similar?

Custom Authorize Logic

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = false;
        var environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Env"];
        var configuredAccountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appserviceaccountname"];
        string incomingServiceAccountName = null;

        try
        {

            if(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal != null && actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity != null)
            {

                incomingServiceAccountName = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(incomingServiceAccountName))
                {
                    logger.Error(string.Format("Service account name passed in is : {0}", incomingServiceAccountName));
                    switch (environment)
                    {
                        case "Dev":
                            if(incomingServiceAccountName.ToLower().Equals(configuredAccountName.ToLower()))
                            {
                                isAuthorized = true;
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
            else if(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal == null)
            {
                logger.Error("Principal is null");
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Error("Identity is null");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(string.Format("Error occurred while authorizing the user inside the class CustomAuthorize and method IsAuthorized with {0}", ex.Message));
            isAuthorized = false;
        }

        return isAuthorized;

    }
}
```

MVC5 Client code that makes the api call

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://webapiurl");
                var jsonString = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(search), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, jsonString).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    mydate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<mydate>>(result);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set Windows Auth in IIS on on the server? IIS Windows Auth providers also must be present (Negotiate, NTLM) to allow IIS to try to authenticate with AD.

Comment: Windows auth on IIS is turned on

Comment: I just realized that you use HttpClient that creates a separate thread and Windows Auth does not allow the new thread to inherit security context. If you insist on using HttpClient you should make sure you set HttpClientHandler.Credentials. Otherwise you can use WebClient that does not create a separeate thread and so passes the Windows credentials.

Comment: You are spot on Ivicz. I changed my client implementation to use WebClient with the UseDefaultCredentials = true. This passes the service account instead of the logged in user account from the client application

Comment: I think here is when you should switch on impersonation on client. Another idea, that maybe you allowed Anonymous Authentication on client that undermines Windows user logon by the Negotiation Provider.  If it does not help, I think I am clueless.