# Calling a Web API hosted on the same server from a controller, the AD name for auth is the IIS app pool name not the user name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, active-directory

APPLICATION DESCRIPTION

The application consist of two functions. Within the controller is a call to the web API as follows:

```
    private async Task<string> CallMciPostsApi()
    {
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var response = await 
                client.GetAsync("https://medapp10.med.state.sbu/emed2webapi/api/mcipost");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                EventLogger.Info(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The controller has        `[Authorize(Roles = ("MED Supervisors Overseas"))]`

Within the razor page an Ajax call:

```
function getCountries() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://medapp10.med.state.sbu/Emed2webapi/api/mcipost');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        loadCountrySelect(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText), true);
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

web.config

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

Web API

```
    [Authorize(Roles = ("MED Supervisors Overseas"))]
[RoutePrefix("api/mcipost")]
public class MciPostController : BaseController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Status Return a list of MciPost objects
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route()]
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var entityList = MCIPostRepository.Get();

            if (entityList == null)
            {
                return InternalServerError();   // 500 Internal Server Error
            }

            if (entityList.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(entityList); // 200 OK
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLogger.Error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

PROBLEM

1. With the web API installed and running the application under Visual
   Studio - IIS Express, the AJAX call fails but the controller call
   succeeds. **Visual Studio is running as local administrator** *Based on an issue with running a post-build script and being unable to see network resources, the fact that VS is running as admin may be significant.*
2. However, with the application installed on the web API host server,
   the opposite occurs and the AJAX call succeeds and the controller
   call fails (response.ReasonPhrase="UnAuthorized").

After many days of research and consulting with colleagues, it remains a mystery why this is so. This is my first time dealing with Active Directory and I suspect I am missing something obvious for someone who has worked with it more extensively.

Regarding problem 2, created a custom authorized attribute to log authorization errors. The active directory name is the 'IIS APPPOOL' name.

1. Tried setting impersonate="true" in the web.config

**

Comment: Might be related to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489205/web-api-authorization-by-capturing-clients-service-account-name?rq=1

I am investigating.

Answer (score 0):

From:
[Web api authorization by capturing client's service account name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489205/web-api-authorization-by-capturing-clients-service-account-name?rq=1)

Changed HttpClient to WebClient (UseDefaultCredentials=true;) and set impersonate=true on web.config.